# Flask how to set cross domain cookie

Tags: cookies, flask

I try to set a cross domain cookie with response like this:

```
@auth.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    resp = make_response('setcookie')
    resp.set_cookie('cookie_1', 'cookie for A', domain='.A.com')
    return resp
```

but it dose not work.I can not see the cookie on '.A.com' in the browser.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting can't be done. (It's a browser security issue)

1.This will take effect on this situation when the app website's domain is **app.a.com** and the main website's domain is **account.a.com** (which you want set a cross cookie ) .Put another way the two sites
have a common one-level-domain (a.com)  name .

2.You may need a solution named Simple Single Sign-On.